# How to save your api response in as a list in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am calling an api whose response is a list of items and I want to store them to response class. My code is:

await
get(

```
  Uri.parse(
      "https://**********/api/Payment/GetDeliveryList?statusid=$statuscode&ShipperId=$shipperid&Rowsperpage=$rows&Page=$page"),
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer $tokens",
  },
).then((response) {
  var data = json.decode(response.body);
  print(data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if response.body is a json List you can simply but it in a `List<Map<String,dynamic>>`

```dart
.then((res) {
  final json = jsonDecode(res.body);
  if (json is List<Map<String,dynamic>>) {
    List<Map<String,dynamic>> myList = json;
  } else {
    print("json is not list");
  }
});
```